# I am using ngx-qrcode to generate a qr code in my angular application. But it is quite small, and I'm unable to increase the width

Tags: angular, qr-code

This is the html and css for the qrcode.Is there any other way I can add width?

```
<div  nz-col *ngIf=showQRCode nzSpan="12" class="background">
   <ngx-qrcode
   [qrc-element-type]="'img'"
   [errorCorrectionLevel]="correctionLevel"
   [value]="value"
   qrc-class = "bshadow"></ngx-qrcode>
</div>

.bshadow{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222222);
   opacity: .5;
   width:200px;
 
 }
```

Comment: EDIT- [width]=500 worked

Answer (score 1):

`[width]=500` in the HTML worked.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried by `cssClass`?

**like this**

```
<div  nz-col *ngIf=showQRCode nzSpan="12" class="background">
   <ngx-qrcode
   [qrc-element-type]="'img'"
   [errorCorrectionLevel]="correctionLevel"
   [value]="value"
   cssClass="bshadow"></ngx-qrcode>
</div>
```

Comment: can you move bshadow class in style.css file and see, will it fix the issue?

Comment: it is in the css file itself